# ex 26 learn c the hard way not executing

Tags: c, makefile

I am having problems running the file.  It seems to compile file but then it gives an error about loading the shared libraries.  I am attaching the devpkg.c (there are multiple other files but I think this is the one that matters) code, the Makefile and the error message.

Makefile:

```
PREFIX?=/usr/local
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -I${PREFIX}/apr/include/apr-1  -I${PREFIX}/apr/include/apr-util-1
LDLIBS=-L${PREFIX}/apr/lib/ -lapr-1 -pthread -laprutil-1

all: devpkg

devpkg: bstrlib.o db.o shell.o commands.o

install: all
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/bin/
    install devpkg $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/bin/

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f devpkg
    rm -rf *.dSYM
```

devpkg.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <apr_general.h>
#include <apr_getopt.h>
#include <apr_strings.h>
#include <apr_lib.h>
#include <apr_pools.h>

#include "dbg.h"
#include "db.h"
#include "commands.h"

int main(int argc, const char const *argv[])
{
    apr_pool_t *p = NULL;
    apr_pool_initialize();
    apr_pool_create(&p, NULL);

    apr_getopt_t *opt;
    apr_status_t rv;

    char ch = '\0';
    const char *optarg = NULL;
    const char *config_opts = NULL;
    const char *install_opts = NULL;
    const char *make_opts = NULL;
    const char *url = NULL;
    enum CommandType request = COMMAND_NONE;


    rv = apr_getopt_init(&opt, p, argc, argv);

    while(apr_getopt(opt, "I:Lc:m:i:d:SF:B:", &ch, &optarg) == APR_SUCCESS) {
        switch (ch) {
            case 'I':
                request = COMMAND_INSTALL;
                url = optarg;
                break;

            case 'L':
                request = COMMAND_LIST;
                break;

            case 'c':
                config_opts = optarg;
                break;

            case 'm':
                make_opts = optarg;
                break;

            case 'i':
                install_opts = optarg;
                break;

            case 'S':
                request = COMMAND_INIT;
                break;

            case 'F':
                request = COMMAND_FETCH;
                url = optarg;
                break;

            case 'B':
                request = COMMAND_BUILD;
                url = optarg;
                break;
        }
    }

    switch(request) {
        case COMMAND_INSTALL:
            check(url, "You must at least give a URL.");
            Command_install(p, url, config_opts, make_opts, install_opts);
            break;

        case COMMAND_LIST:
            DB_list();
            break;

        case COMMAND_FETCH:
            check(url != NULL, "You must give a URL.");
            Command_fetch(p, url, 1);
            log_info("Downloaded to %s and in /tmp/", BUILD_DIR);
            break;

        case COMMAND_BUILD:
            check(url, "You must at least give a URL.");
            Command_build(p, url, config_opts, make_opts, install_opts);
            break;

        case COMMAND_INIT:
            rv = DB_init();
            check(rv == 0, "Failed to make the database.");
            break;

        default:
            sentinel("Invalid command given.");
    }


    return 0;

error:
    return 1;
}
```

Error message:

```
$ make clean;make
rm -f *.o
rm -f devpkg
rm -rf *.dSYM
cc -g -Wall -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-util-1   -c -o bstrlib.o bstrlib.c
cc -g -Wall -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-util-1   -c -o db.o db.c
cc -g -Wall -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-util-1   -c -o shell.o shell.c
cc -g -Wall -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-util-1   -c -o commands.o commands.c
cc -g -Wall -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-util-1    devpkg.c bstrlib.o db.o shell.o commands.o  -L/usr/local/apr/lib/ -lapr-1 -pthread -laprutil-1 -o devpkg
$ ./devpkg
./devpkg: error while loading shared libraries: libapr-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

First of all why am I getting this error when I am running it, why doesn't this happen when I compile it, is it because at runtime all the files are calling this library and it can't be shared across the different files (but that doesn't seem to quite make sense to me?  Please let me know if you need more information and I can add it in.

Comment: Install the package which contains that library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling converts your source files to binary. This phase does not involve the libraries. So, when you compile, missing libraries are not noticed and you get no errors.

Linking is the second phase where your binaries and the libraries you referenced are put together into an executable file. In this phase, if the libraries you referenced cannot be found, the executable cannot be built. This is the error that you are getting here. The linker cannot find apr-1. Look for the folder /usr/local/apr/lib/ and see if the library files are there. If not either put them there or change the make file to tell the linker where they actually are.